# Rails - Where Like query is not returning results that are all capital letters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote this search function which works in all cases except where the words are made up of all capital letters. So if I have a product "EVGA", it will not show up in search results. If I were to change the name to "Evga", it would appear.

Can someone please tell me what the issue is here that is causing this?

product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord

  def self.search(search)
    products = Product.all
    products = products.where("title like ?", "%#{search.capitalize}%") if search
    products
  end
...
end
```

products_controller.rb

```
def index
  @products = Product.search(params[:title])
end
```

and in the view...

```
<fieldset class="search">
  <%= form_tag products_path, method: :get, class: "product_search" do %>
    <div class="search-field">
      <%= text_field_tag :title, params[:search], placeholder: "Search all products..." %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Does this work `products.where("title ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%") if search`?

Comment: Yes it does! I haven't seen ILIKE before.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `search.capitalize`? Note that the `ilike` operator is PostgreSQL-specific.

Comment: Yes, it seems to only work with ILIKE for whatever reason. Using search and search.capitalize return the same results. Fortunately I'm using Postgresql so I'm in luck.